# Are some jobs more dreamy than others?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Is it just me or do you get some dream jobs way more often than others? In my case it is Holochess Hall and Mos Espa Café. I made at least 60 bux from employing these people, but my Lightsaber Craft still has got just one star and I'm pretty sure that that's the only bitizen who ever wanted to work there.

**Is it possible that the better and more expensive floor, the rarer the dream jobs?**

Comment: Pretty sure its completely random...

Comment: it's possible that I've just got really bad luck, but this is not what random feels like :-D if that was the case the distribution of the jobs would be 1:1:1:1:1 etc., which in my case it is not...

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten dream job bitizens for many of my more expensive levels, yet some of my cheaper ones have no starred folks.

In fact, I have many people whose dream job is to work in a more expensive level that I do not have yet.

Answer (score 1):

My experience shows me that there are dreamier jobs. But I don't think its about being more expensive floors. I do get a lot of dream jobbers for more expensive levels which I do not yet have. I created a question as well for this subject. I am curious about its odds.

[What are the odds of getting dream jobs for certain levels?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159029/what-are-the-odds-of-getting-dream-jobs-for-certain-levels/159030?noredirect=1#159030)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the dream job assigned is done by a random number generator, which has a bell-curve output.  Therefore you get a large number of the same businesses as dream jobs, (around the 50% mark) and very few of others (outliers at <10%, >90%).

As far as which business is assigned which random number, I don't know...