# What are the odds of getting dream jobs for certain levels?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I thought it was coincidence at first but now I am certain that some jobs get more dream jobbers. For me:

- Toydarian Toys
- Mon Cala Aquarium
- Holochess Hall

I get dream jobbers for these levels twice everyday. I have 50 levels so it is really unusual when always the same ones get dream jobbers. These are some of the least expensive levels. But there are also other levels in this category which doesn't get the same attention.

Is there tiers? Like x,y,z levels 1% dream jobs, a,b,c levels 5% dream jobs? How does the system work?

Answer (score 1):

My observations are that the dream job distribution appears random across possible levels.  With many bitizens coming through, there are bound to be some repeats from time to time and they may appear to be clumping into groups.  It's easy to see patterns in randomly distributed data that aren't really there and I think that's what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

The dream job distribution is random, and so from a probability standpoint you will get several bitizens with the same dream job, but none with a dream job of another level.

Most users choose to evict bitizens after they have maxed a level with "dream jobbers" in order to solve this problem.

Comment: It's a good idea to save the bitizen, give him his dream job and then evict him.

Answer (score 0):

My observation is that the same few kinds of dream jobbers always appear in certain residential floors.

I once had 3 of the same dream jobbers (out of 5 new residents) on the same floor when I used a recruiting agent VIP on the floor. Since I already have three 9-rated dream jobbers at that shop, I promptly evicted these 3 new ones after giving them a taste of doing their dream jobs. But when I used another recruiting agent VIP, I saw other dream jobbers of the same shop appear again, but only one this time.

Sometimes when my residential level is full, and I evict the less skilled resident, I would sometimes get dream jobber of the same one I evicted after a few rounds of booting others.

So I think certain residential levels would only have dream jobbers while other residential levels would have other sets of dream jobbers.